# Term.js - page scrolls down to the section with the terminal

Tags: javascript

This is probably a silly question - I'm using [term.js](https://github.com/chjj/term.js/) to simulate a linux terminal.

Everything works fine. The only issue I am having is - the page where I have embedded it is pretty long and this terminal is somewhere at the bottom - but as soon as the page loads - it automatically scrolls down to the bottom of the page with the terminal.

I've been going through the [term.js code](https://github.com/chjj/term.js/blob/master/src/term.js) commenting and trying different things to remove focus - but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it: What do I have to change in term.js to disable the automatic scrolling?

Comment: Yes - basically I dont want the page to scroll all the way down to the section where I have the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`term.open()` does a focus for the terminal at the end of the function. Simply comment it out and it won't scroll down to the terminal.

At line 801:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
      self.element.focus();
  }, 100);
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hakito/v18Lcogq/2/) to demonstrate it.

As an alternative to modifying the code you could

- put the terminal into an iframe.
- load the terminal dynamically on a user event (button click).

Comment: Thats perfect - Thanks a ton Gerd - for some reason I never played with that piece assuming its an IPad fix. Appreciate you taking the time.